# Intel TBB run a function in a parallel thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, tbb

Basically I am developing an opencv application. I have built **OpenCV** `with_tbb` option in `cmake`.

I would like to use intel tbb to run a parallel thread that at some intervals updates some global variables. Something like:

```
vector<int> mySharedVar;

void secondaryThreadFunction() {
 while(true) {
   Do some operations
   And update mySharedVar if necessarily  

   usleep(1000);
 }
}

int main() {
   run in parallel secondaryThreadFunction;

   in the master Thread keep doing something based on mySharedVar

   while(true) {
    do something;
   }
}
```

How can I run `secondaryThreadFunction()` on another thread ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel TBB is not meant to be used for that kind of purpose.
Quote from the [Tutorial](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/uploads/81/91/Latest%20Open%20Source%20Documentation/Tutorial.pdf):

> Intel® Threading Building Blocks targets threading for performance.
>   Most general-purpose threading packages support many different kinds
>   of threading, such as threading for asynchronous events in graphical
>   user interfaces. As a result, general-purpose packages tend to be
>   low-level tools that provide a foundation, not a solution. Instead,
>   Intel® Threading Building Blocks focuses on the particular goal of
>   parallelizing computationally intensive work, delivering higher-level,
>   simpler solutions.

The thing you wanna do can be easily achived with either `boost::thread` or the C++11 threading features:

```
   // using async
   auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, secondaryThreadFunction);
   // using threads (for boost, just replace std with boost)
   std::thread async_thread(secondaryThreadFunction);

   in the master Thread keep doing something based on mySharedVar

   while(true) {
    do something;
   }

   // in case of using threads
   async_thread.join();
```

Keep in mind to sync the access to any shared variables.